# Prefix source paths in the output of `npm build`

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-scripts

I have created a small vue application using vue-cli. I use `npm run build` to produce the production version of the UI, which ends up with a bunch of CSS, js, and an HTML page file that has all of those js and CSS files. However, for the purpose of the application, the HTML needs to be moved to a different directory, where is it accessed by the middleware. That is why the URL of the js and CSS files need to be prefixed, to point to the new direcotry. Is it possible to create a prefix in the output HTML file for the js and CSS files?

Here is the content of the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "investmentapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.18.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

P.S. Currently, I have written a separate script that does this automatically, but I was looking for an in-built option. Also, I would be keen to build this into `npm run serve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the files in your package.json scripts by adding a 'copy' script that you can reuse in build and serve.

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve && npm run copy",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build && npm run copy",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "copy": "cp src/*.html destinationDir"
  },
```

As for prefixing the CSS and JS urls, presuming you are using webpack, you can do that in the webpack.config.js. Something along the lines of:

```
output: {
  filename: '../PrefixDir/[name].[chunkhash].js',
  ...
},
```

Comment: Nice, I can use my python code in the `copy` script. I am not sure if webpack is being used under the hood of `vue-cli-service`, but I can check for the config file. Otherwise, I might couple it with webpack myself.